# CSS me genera un espacio en blanco

Tags: html, css, web

estoy haciendo una página web, en este caso el `layout`, y tengo un problema con el `CSS` ya que este me genera un pequeño espacio en blanco entre el fondo ("wallpaper") y el `footer`. El código es el siguiente:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #333;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo {
height: 40px;
width: 200px;
padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
fill: #000;
}

.input_query {
flex-basis: 25%;
height: 18px;
border: 1px solid #282828;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px;
}

.log_in {
margin-left: auto;
color: #DCDCDC;
}

.log_in_btn {
background-color: #3F3F3F;
margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #282828;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.wallpaper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href=""><img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo-web.png"></a>
        <input class="input_query" placeholder="Search...">
        <section class="log_in">
            <a href="" class="log_in_btn">Sing in</a>
            <a href="" class="log_in_btn">Create an account</a>
        </section>
    </header>
    <img src="assets/images/wallpaper.png" class="wallpaper">
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El famoso *espacio misterioso* resulta que es por culpa de los `DOCTYPE` estrictos  y modernos.

Veamos unos ejemplos con este trozo de código:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Si tenemos un doctype: `HTML 4.01 Transitional` podemos ver que todo esta en su orden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Ver Demo](http://jsbin.com/xexuja/edit?html,output)

---

Ahora bien... Si usamos ahora un **DOCTYPE** *estricto* `HTML 4.01 Strict` o *moderno* `HTML5` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Ver Demo](http://jsbin.com/havide/edit?html,output)

vemos que ahora nos aparece un espacio entre la imagen y el borde!

---

Si leemos un poco en [Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Im%C3%A1genes,_tablas_y_huecos_misteriosos) sobre los *huecos* misteriosos, nos dice:

> A partir de 2001 y el auge de los navegadores conformes que muestran
>   las páginas usando HTML y CSS en vez de sus propios algoritmos de
>   diseño, y a causa de un detalle poco conocido de la especificación de
>   CSS, todo diseño basado en maquetación con tablas e imágenes
>   espaciadoras se ha convertido en un desastre visual esperando ser
>   visitado. Todo lo que necesitas es un navegador moderno, un DOCTYPE
>   apropiado, y... ¡Boom!

Ahora sabemos de donde viene el asunto :)

Hay varias maneras/trucos de solucionarlo:

- Poner la imagen en [display: block;](http://jsbin.com/loyafu/edit?html,css,output)
- Poner la imagen en [vertical-align: top / middle / bottom;](http://jsbin.com/foqevi/edit?html,css,output)
- Poner los elementos padres en [line-height: 0;](http://jsbin.com/cowepe/edit?html,css,output)
- Poner los elementos padres en [font-size: 0;](http://jsbin.com/bajini/edit?html,css,output)

**Conclusión:**

Según tu maquetación te puede servir una que otra solución/truco para este problema. 
En tu caso puedes usar: `display: inherit;`, `display: block;` o `display: flex;`

[Leer más sobre recomendaciones Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Im%C3%A1genes,_tablas_y_huecos_misteriosos#Recomendaciones)

Comment: Me había encontrado muchas veces con ese problema y sabía como solucionarlo pero no tenía ni idea de que tenía relación con el `doctype`. Interesante información.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si es un bug o una característica de `inline-block` pero es algo que sucede siempre. En tu caso usas una imagen que por defecto su valor de `display` es `inline-block`, para solucionarlo puedes ponerle `display:block` a la imagen y ya está, desaparecerá el espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de responderte dejame darte un un consejo y es que primero no pongas un `<section>` dentro de un `<header>` para eso existen los `<div>`. Los section son para el cuerpo del HTML.

Ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta por defecto siempre queda una linea entre los section y el `<footer>` para poder quitar esta linea agregarle un `margin-top: -3px` en el footer, quedaria entonces asi.

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: -3px;
    }
```

Comment: Ah vale, gracias, pensaba que <section> era más específico que <div>.

Comment: @Raúl No tiene nada que ver con el `section`, de hecho en tu código el espacio está entre la imagen y el `footer`. El problema es la propiedad `display:inline-block`

Comment: Ya ya, me refería a lo de que no pusiese `<section>` y usase `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he conseguido solucionar, no se el porqué pero el comentario de la persona que me lo ha dicho no me apraece. La solución era añadirle a `.wallpaper` `display: flex;` pero no entiendo el porqué

Comment: funciona con `display: flex` porque cambias el `display` por defecto de la imagen, tambien te funcionara con `display: block` y con otros valores de `display`.

Comment: Probablemente hayas solucionado el problema para el visionado en tu navegador con 'display: flex'. Deberías probarlo en otros navegadores. De todos modos, yo agregaría 'border: 0' a todos los elementos (ya que solamente aplicas 'margin: 0' y 'padding: 0'). Entiendo que el problema es el modelo de cajas que usa cada navegador.